# How do I setup Ghost EC2 instance with git so I can push changes from my local copy

Tags: git, amazon-ami, ghost-blog

I followed the instructions for setting up Ghost on EC2. I used the following [AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00HJDY0DY/ref=sp_mpg_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2). It was very simple and my new Ghost site is up and running. I was also able to SSH into the instance just fine.

Now I'd like to use git to pull down the site locally to my system and then publish back to the EC2 instance whenever I make changes. I noticed that git is already installed on the instance and it looks like ghost is installed in the /home/ghost directory.

Problem I'm having is when I try to CD into that directory I get a permission denied message.  Also, I have no clue what address I would use to clone the repo from once I set up the ghost site on the AMI with git. My assumption is the site on the AMI is already under git version control.

Any instruction on how to get this setup would be much appreciated.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Ghost is actually installed at /var/www/ghost. You should be able to create a git repo in that directory and clone it to your local machine to make changes and push them back.

The AMI is not currently under git control. If it is installed, then it may have been a dependency of something else, because it was not a feature we were trying to add when we created the AMI.

Hopefully some of that info helps you out! Good luck!